# Org mode not returning last evaluated line of lisp

Tags: org-mode

I can't figure out why evaluating this lisp code with C-c C-c doesn't return 832040 and instead returns the function name FIB:

```
#+begin_src lisp
  (defun fib (n)
    "Return the nth Fibonacci number"
    (if (< n 2)
    n
    (+ (fib (- n 1))
       (fib (- n 2))))))

  (fib 30)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: FIB
```

Running the function with input 30 again yields the expected result:

```
#+begin_src lisp
  (fib 30)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 832040
```

...what on earth am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: **extra bracket at end of function.** Remove it and `C-c C-c` will evaluate everything as expected.

```lisp
  (defun fib (n)
    "Return the nth Fibonacci number"
    (if (< n 2)
    n
    (+ (fib (- n 1))
       (fib (- n 2)))))
```

As per other answers, `C-c C-c` evaluates the entire code block wherever the cursor is, and `C-x C-e` evaluates the sexp the cursor is placed at the end of.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `C-c C-c` evaluates the closest sexp to point or to the mouse pointer.

There are *two* sexps in that Org block. The first is a defun, and evaluating it returns the function name as a symbol. Looks like that's what's happening: you're asking to evaluate the defun and return the result of that evaluation.

Comment: Checked [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Evaluating-Code-Blocks) to make sure I am asking a sane question.

With the point on either expression, the result is still the function name.

Thank you for the great suggestion.

Comment: I use `C-x C-e` to evaluate a lisp expression. Is `C-c C-c` also used? When I tried it I got `C-c C-c is undefined`. And `C-c C-c is not listed in the manual
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Evaluating-Emacs-Lisp-code.html#:~:text=Typing%20C%2Dx%20C%2De%20in%20any,evaluated%20once%20you%20press%20RET%20.

Comment: @zeynel: No idea; I don't use Org. ;-) But `C-c C-c` is what OP wrote in the question, apparently thinking it would evaluate everything in the Org block. I'm guessing it just evals the sexp at point (or at the mouse pointer).

Comment: The correct answer is "I have an extra bracket at the end of my function", haha! For future reference, yes, `C-c C-c` evaluates the entire code block wherever the cursor is, and `C-x C-e` evaluates the sexp the cursor is placed at the end of. *Appreciate the wink Drew, lol.*